# Simple raster calculation in batch mode (for folders)

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, command-line

I have thousands of raster organized in several folders. All of their cell values have to be divided by 10. Seems simple, but I didn't find any solution to do it in batch. QGIS offers batch mode, but all raster calculators (SAGA, GRASS, GDAL) are way to complex for simply filling the batch parameters.

I'm sure, there must be a simple command to do that calculation:  `[Raster Folder] / 10`.

(working on ubuntu)

Comment: My gut feeling for this, is that I would do it as a (python) script from the cli, not within qgis. Are all your rasters the same format?

Comment: yes, they are all in *.tif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using the CLI I suggest to use [`gdal_calc.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html); assuming you have both *GDAL* and its *Python* bindings set up to be accessed via Bash (alternatively, use the *OSGeo4W* shell), run

```
for raster in <in_dir>/*.<format_extension>
  do gdal_calc.py --calc="A/10" -A $raster --outfile <out_dir>/${raster##*/}
done
```

where `<format_extension>` is the respective file format ending, e.g. `.tif`. Note that this example does *not* like file names with spaces!

This will

- loop over all files in `<in_dir>` that have the specified suffix
  `<format_extension>`, and store the respecive (full) path into the `raster` variable
- call `gdal_calc.py` on each, applying the expression
  `A/10` on each pixel
  (the `-A` flag and respective identifier `A` in the calculation expression are linked, and generic;
  you can name multiple input source files with a different letter, and
  refer to their cell values with the same)
- save the generated file to `<out_dir>` with the same name as the
  input file; you can add a string here to mark the processed files as such, e.g. `-outfile <out_dir>/reclassified_${raster##*/}` (see link below) (you could even overwrite the input files, but I would not recommend that; thus the `<out_dir>`)

If your raster files are of different type, you can either just leave out the file extension, or add a list of extensions to consider; the shell is highly versatile with its parameters, but has *plenty* of traps to fall into; refer to the *Bash* manual, e.g. [*Shell Parameter Expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

---

To simply **overwrite** all raster files in a directory tree (including subfolders), run

```
for raster in <in_dir_root>/*.<format_extension> <in_dir_root>/**/*.<format_extension> <in_dir_root>/**/**/*.<format_extension>
  do gdal_calc.py --calc="A/10" -A $raster --outfile $raster
done
```

where you add a path with an additional `.../**/...` for each level of subfolders in the tree; there are more sophisticated ways, but none as easy...